# Is there a way to apply different summary functions in dplyr depending on variable group?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to summarize variables in dplyr with different aggregating functions being used for different groups of columns.  For example the code below will `min` over the vowel columns and `max` over the consonants, but it is cumbersome and changes column order.

```
library(tidyverse)

vowels <- c("a","e","i","o","u")

df %>% 
  select(one_of(vowels)) %>% summarize_all(min) %>% 
  bind_cols(df %>% select(-one_of(vowels)) %>% summarize_all(max))
```

I know that I could use `summarize_all(funs(min,max))` and then subset to the columns I need, but that also seems non-optimal, especially in non-trivial cases where the summary functions might be computationally expensive.

I really would like a function which takes in paired groupings of variables and functions (i.e. `summarize_at2(vars(one_of(vowels),-one_of(vowels)), funs(min,max))`).  Maybe there is some clean way to do this using `purrr`?

Comment: How would you want the output? Do you want a single column that has the max for the vowels and the min for the non-vowels? Or two columns with `NA` values when the summary is for a different group? Something else? This would be a much better question if you provided some sample input and desired output.

Comment: I mean you can write your own `summarize_at2` function as a wrapper, but you should think about the desired structure for output. What if your groups aren't neat complements? E.g. if a single column is summarised more than once in your new function? There is no way to preserve column order in that case, which means something similar to your first solution (and a subsequent reorder if you really want it) is basically as good as you're going to get i think.